# Guidance in what kind of navigation this app has used

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Im new to monotouch but want to build an app that is something similar to this.

The 1st image is the home screen you see when you open the app if your logged in.

Pressing each of the buttons or images navigates you to a view like the 2nd image.

[image]

How would I build something similar, Im using the latest beta 5.1.1 that I believe contains the monotouch.dialog baked into it.

Would I be able to do something like this with monotouch.dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first screen looks more like what [three20](http://three20.info/gallery) can do (i.e. I'm not sure how I could do that with MonoTouch.Dialog without a bit of work - but I never tried something like that). There are MonoTouch [bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/Three20) for Three20 available on github.

The second and third screen are more in line with what [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) can do, right out of the box (or it's [Sample](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/tree/master/Sample) test app). They are not all *standard* `Element` but the library is easy to customize, by inheritance, to get almost anything you want (e.g. down to owner-drawn elements).

There's a lot of questions (**with** answers) that covers MonoTouch.Dialog. If you hit any problem, to achieve something specific, then you're welcome to ask them here on stackoverflow!

Comment: Apple design guidelines advise against having a wall of icons like the first shot.   Their reason is that users do not have an ability to remember the icons in apps and it is a bad user experience.